# How to keep "*" in VIEW output clause so that columns track table changes?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating an Oracle view like this :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE;
```

When I create the view, I notice that oracle changes the view query to something like :

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2,... FROM TABLE;
```

My problem is that if I change the TABLE structure, add a new field for instance, the changes are not taken into consideration in the view. I have then to recreate the view, and regrant privileges on this view to the users/roles.

Is there any way to make a view mode generic and keep it as the form of : SELECT * FROM TABLE ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to simply ALTER the view from the original definition, no? In SQL it doesn't really make sense that a view has the "`*`" shape any more than it makes sense for a table to have no shape - the column wildcard is mostly a hack for lazy humans who just want some output-right-now :)

Comment: This is just an example. The idea is how to get the current table structure whatever happens ? Let's assume it's : SELECT * FROM TABLE where ID = x. I would like to get all the current fields of the table.

Comment: Having a view automatically track column changes could cause problems with your application code if it isn't similarly flexible. So keep that in mind if you do find a solution.

Comment: @ThomasCarlton SQL sets have a strong shape. Such a view definition goes against this concept. If you really desire this behavior I would keep the original view definitions - such that the definitions are stored in separate files or whatnot - and then create-or-replace/alter the views based on some trigger. If you're versioning the schema using an external tool (e.g. with a Schema Diff + RoundHousE) it's fairly trivial to set this up to be automatic. In particular, RoundHousE as "anytime scripts" (although I think that such a concept is fundamentally broken and version everything lock-step).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot define a simple view that would automatically change its structure when the underlying table changes.  When new columns are added, you'll need to touch the view.  You'll almost certainly need to do as @GordonLinoff suggests and do a `CREATE OR REPLACE` when the table changes.  Given that changes to tables should be rare and should involve proper change control, touching the view as part of the change should be a relatively simple step.

If you're really determined to avoid having to touch the view, there are some alternatives.  I generally wouldn't recommend these because they are very likely to increase rather than decrease the complexity of maintaining your system.  But if you have a third party system that is generating DDL to add columns on an unpredictable basis, maybe it makes sense.

You could create a DDL trigger that fires in response to statements that `ALTER` the table and that submits a job using `dbms_job` that re-creates the view.  That's quite a few moving pieces but it's generally workable.

Alternately, instead of a view, you could create a pipelined table function that returns a variable number of columns.  That's going to be [really complicated](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4843682300346852395#5421020800346627246) but it's also pretty slick.  There aren't many places that I'd feel comfortable using that approach simply because there aren't many people that can look at that code and have a chance of maintaining it.  But the code is pretty slick.

Answer (score 6):

The `*` is evaluated when the view is created, not when it is executed.  In fact, Oracle compiles views for faster execution.  It uses the compiled code when the view is referenced.  It does not just do a text substitution into the query.

The proper syntax for changing a view is:

```
create or replace view v_table as
    select *
    from table;
```

Comment: Does create-or-replace preserve privileges and such in Oracle? (I presume it will almost always be a replace operation here.)

Comment: @user2864740 . . . Yes it does.

Comment: This is my question, I don't want to touch the view any more once created. The view is defined by : SELECT * FROM TABLE. Is it possible to keep "*" in it what ever happens in the table ?

Comment: @ThomasCarlton . . . I don't think that you can tell Oracle to automatically recompile a view when the underlying tables change structure.  Instead, Oracle invalidates them.  However, you can just execute the same `create or replace` code to recreate the view (or `alter view compile`.

Answer (score 0):

I have face this same issue and created a procedure which accepts the name of the table and creates the view:

```
str := 'create or replace view xyz.'|| tablename_in ||'_v as select * from '|| tablename_in;

execute immediate str;
```

Then in Toad (not sure if you use Toad), in the schema browser, right click on the table name, and then select 'Custom Queries' -->  'Edit Custom Queries' and then have it call your procedure as:

```
exec view_create<ObjectList>
```

Then you can right click on the table name and in one click create the view as Toad will pass the name of the table into the procedure.

Also in the procedure you may want to recompile the schema, so after the view is created do:

```
 sys.utl_recomp.recomp_parallel(4, 'XYZ');
```

If you develop a script of some sort which can semi automate, it makes things easy.

Hope this helps...